# Why am I getting Cassandra prepared statement recreation error on startup from dropped keyspaces?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am running a  2 node (8 cores per node) Cassandra 3.10 cluster with a replication factor of 1.   I have and have had a number of keyspaces over time on my cassandra cluster.

I have noticed lately that when I stop/start the times to come back up are extremely slow.   I am seen thousands of **"prepared statement recreation"**  stack traces as per below example in both my system.log and debug.log.   It appears that Cassandra is attempting to prepare statements for keyspaces that no longer exist as I have previously dropped them.

Note I do not have any application/client etc connected to cassandra when its starting up.  I have also manually cleaned out the the commitlog, saved_caches along with the data files for the previously drop keysapces and this makes no difference upon startup.  I see the same behaviour with our without the data and commit logs.

Anyone know where Cassandra is getting this information from upon startup and/or how to resolve this while preserving existing keyspaces?

Prepared statement recreation warning:

```
WARN  [main] 2017-07-07 14:44:14,362 QueryProcessor.java:159 - prepared statement recreation error: update metric_resource set attributes = ? where t_uid ='TUID1' and metric_name =? and resource_name=?
org.apache.cassandra.db.KeyspaceNotDefinedException: Keyspace test_keyspace_1 does not exist
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateKeyspace(ThriftValidation.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateColumnFamily(ThriftValidation.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement$Parsed.prepare(ModificationStatement.java:796) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.ModificationStatement$Parsed.prepare(ModificationStatement.java:789) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.getStatement(QueryProcessor.java:557) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.prepare(QueryProcessor.java:412) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.preloadPreparedStatement(QueryProcessor.java:154) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:358) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
```

Other stack traces relating to non existing keyspace:

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.KeyspaceNotDefinedException: Keyspace test_keyspace1 does not exist
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateKeyspace(ThriftValidation.java:85) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.ThriftValidation.validateColumnFamily(ThriftValidation.java:109) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$RawStatement.prepare(SelectStatement.java:920) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.SelectStatement$RawStatement.prepare(SelectStatement.java:915) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.getStatement(QueryProcessor.java:557) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.prepare(QueryProcessor.java:412) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryProcessor.preloadPreparedStatement(QueryProcessor.java:154) ~[apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:358) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:601) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:735) [apache-cassandra-3.10.jar:3.10]
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured this one out.  Cassandra writes prepared statements to **system.prepared_statements** keyspace.  Not too sure when they introduced this feature.   It appears to keep all prepared statements in this table and attempts to read them upon a restart.  I have millions of rows in my instance including those from previously dropped keyspaces.

Truncating the table system.prepared_statements resolved the problem for me and startup times went from hours to seconds.

Truncate table:

```
truncate system.prepared_statements;
```